# Apache RewriteRule - more parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am wondering, how can I correctly convert addresses using .htaccess like `/?menu=first` to `/first`.
Ok actually this works already with code bellow:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [NC]
```

But there is a problem, because it could happend, that once it would be only one parameter in url and another time two or even three parameters. Like this:

```
/?menu=first                               /first
/?menu=first&submenu=second                /first/second
/?menu=first&submenu=second&news=third     /first/second/third
```

Is this possible to achieve using .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, it is. As for the how – do some research please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will 2 additional rules for longer URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&news=$3 [L,QSA]
```

- Also for css/js better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
- You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now, when I try it out using two parameters, browser doesn't seems to find css files. Even more...insted of /css/style.css it searches for same css file using this url /first/css/style.css

Comment: Strange, it stil doesn't work for me.
error looks like this: GET http://localhost:8888/bh_business/css/page/style.css 404 (Not Found)
"bh_business" shouldn't be there

Comment: That means your URLs aren't starting from `http://`, a must for pretty URL schemes.

Comment: So...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page/style.css">
should be
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8888/css/page/style.css">

will this make a diference?

Comment: Yes `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8888/css/page/style.css">` would surely make a difference assuming `/css/page/style.css` is a valid path.

Comment: Indeed. You are right. It works now. But to avoid hardcoded url(localhost...) I could read url using php. Is that good practice?

Comment: I believe `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/page/style.css">` may also work fine.